# Why do local HTML files take longer to load in IE compared to Firefox?

Tags: html

I am creating a local HTML file that links to 2 external CSS files and 3 external JS files.

When I refresh this in Internet Explorer 9, the page takes over a minute to load compared to instantly in Firefox (latest stable build. When I remove the external CSS and JS references, IE9 loads the page instantly.

Can anyone explain why IE9 takes so long to load local HTML files with references to external CSS and JS files?

Comment: Have you verified the same symptoms with a different machine? I suspect it's caching settings - FireFox could have the CSS/JS files cached and IE9 is set to not cache (Which is an HTTPRequest every time for every file).

Comment: It's basically impossible to say unless we have some kind of test page or details on what exactly the external files are.

Comment: Are these files external to your page, but still local to your system? Or are they external in terms of being located on another server far far away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which version of IE you're using, you may see a message like this when you run a webpage locally - "Internet Explorer has restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls"

An oversimplified answer is that there is security check that happens due to the zone the web page runs in. Read the nitty gritty [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224211417/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx).

You can override the check [by serving content from a web server](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224211417/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx) or [adding the Mark of the Web comment between the DOCTYPE and the HTML tag](https://mvark.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-avoid-ie-information-bar-during.html).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments. It could be cache settings and/or browser settings, and I will also add that it could be one or more add-ons slowing you down. I recommend clearing the cache, double checking all of your settings, and disabling any add-ons. You might also want to try reinstalling the browser, and rebooting your system.

It is also true that it's impossible to look for bugs if we can't duplicate the problem you're having. Unless we can see the behavior any answer we can offer would be pure speculation.

Answer (score 0):

I have been suffering the same problem for a long time. Recently I found out it is because of a plugin call infoatoms, after uninstalling it, problem solved. Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not have that plugin installed, thanks for the response though.